# Query on MS ACCESS

Tags: sql, ms-access

I've created a database which look something like:

TABLE:

```
PATIENT ID      CONDITION      DOCTOR      DATE ADMITTED
PATIENT 1       CONDITION 1    DOCTOR 1    5/23/2011
PATIENT 2       CONDITION 1    DOCTOR 2    8/22/2011
PATIENT 3       CONDITION 2    DOCTOR 1    12/12/2010
```

TABLE2:

```
PATIENT ID     CONDITION     DOCTOR      DATE CHANGED
PATIENT 1      CONDITION 4   DOCTOR 3    5/24/2011
PATIENT 1      CONDITION 3   DOCTOR 3    6/22/2011
PATIENT 2      CONDITION 1   DOCTOR 1    10/22/2011
```

I want to get the condition and the doctor on a specific date that would look something like: (number of patients having condition x over certain date)

```
 DATE            5/1/2012    5/2/2012    5/3/2012
 ====================================================
 CONDITION 1       5            2           1
 CONDITION 2       2            1           2
```

AND number of patients who got condition x on certain date (e.g. (3 patients have condition 1, but on 1 patient got condition 1 on may 1,2012 so it will yield 1 instead of 3)

I'm doing this on ms-access by the way.

Comment: Joined those two tables to get the current conditions of each patient, then pivot it to get the number of conditions over certain dates. So my problem now is query#2. I need to get the number of patients who got condition x at a given date. I need to get number of condition x which was changed from condition y at date z. Currently my database looks like the 2 tables above. I was thinking of addition another field "Previous Condition".

Comment: If you can find a way to do this without me having to add another field, that would be great!.

Comment: Posting an expected output based on the sample data you have provided might be more useful.

Answer (score 0):

Create a crosstab on a union query.

```
SELECT Condition, Doctor, [Date Admitted]
FROM [Table]

UNION

SELECT Condition, Doctor, [Date Changed]
FROM Table2
```

This creates a 3 column table without regard to if there are any equalities. If you want to restrict on any criteria, you will have to put the `WHERE` statement in each of the union queries, or in the crosstab query itself